# sum() each quantity which have same id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Hi Guys this is my Table called "inputs". I would like to sum the values having the same TID :

```
re   |  in_ID|   Value  |
========================= 
 1   |   1   |   3  | 
 2   |   1   |   3  |  
 3   |   1   |   4  |  
 4   |   1   |   5  |  
 5   |   2   |   3  |  
 6   |   2   |   3  |  
 7   |   2   |   2  |  
 8   |   2   |   2  |
```

my result should be like that

```
in_ID| sum(Value)|
==================   
 1   |   14      |   
 2   |   20      |
```

my attempt is:

```php
public function sum(){        
    return production_input::select('in_id' , 'value')->sum('value')->groupBy(['in_id']);
}
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: not getting result as I describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
public function sum(){
        return production_input::select([\DB::raw("SUM(value) as value"), 'in_id'])
                                 ->groupBy('in_id')
                                 ->get();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . can you describe how actually this work?

Comment: can this work with out Raw query ie \DB::raw("SUM(value) as value"), 'in_id'])
                                 ->groupBy('in_id')

Comment: when you use groupBy with `in_id` it'll convert it in `in_id` group wise. after sum function will sum `value` in-group. and select function will select `in_id` and `value` of sum. in return you'll get only `in_id` with sum of in_id :)

Comment: `can this work with out Raw query` yes it'll. use  `->selectRaw('sum(value) as sum, in_id')`